# extbase "An error occurred while trying to call", only before cleaning Cache

Tags: extbase, typo3-7.x

I have a extension which runs with parameter no_cache=1 t ensure i always have fresh data. There is a strange behaviour. After a certain while (for example a night) the call of a showAction brings the error:

```
An error occurred while trying to call XYZ showAction()
```

My Controller Action has already @dontvalidate $component.

Using the script of oliver (https://gist.github.com/oliverthiele/f1550a246dd8726ef136) shows up an error

```
The given subject was NULL
```

If I log in into the Typo3 Backend, cleanup all Caches and reload the page which previousely hat the error above everything is fine. Do I have a Cache Issue or do I have a validation issue?

Answer (score 0):

After some more investigation we're almost sure the problem was coming from the ldap extension (ig_ldap_sso_auth). The "error" only occured on properties extending FE-Users, the following post may help: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/71265

Since the fix is applied the error newer came up again.